# How can we read csv file in asp.net core using CsvHelper?

Tags: .net, csv, asp.net-core

how to read and write csv file in asp.net core using CsvHelper

Comment: Review this link you might get help https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why CsvHelper not reading from MemoryStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434920/why-csvhelper-not-reading-from-memorystream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to write the code? Have you looked at the examples online?

Note that [SoftCircuits.CsvParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoftCircuits.CsvParser/) is about four times faster than CsvHelper for some operations. Here's what it would look like to read a file using SoftCircuits.CsvParser:

```
string[] columns = null;
using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(path))
{
    while (reader.ReadRow(ref columns))
    {
        // Here columns contains an array of string values that
        // were read from the current line
    }
}
```

Note that both libraries also have the ability to map the columns directly to object properties so you can just create your class that has a property corresponding to each column, and everything will be mapped for you. The example above simply reads the columns as an array of strings.